# How to find if a date for a particular ID falls within multiple date ranges

Tags: excel

I have a set of transaction data - promotion if and date of sale. In another sheet i have a list of promotions and the days on which they were run.

I want to know if for a transaction carrying a certain promo id on a give date really had a promotion or not.

[image]

Is it possible to check for this either using formulas or vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() to find if any of the criteria match:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,A3,H:H,"<=" &B3,I:I,">=" &B3)>0,"GOOD","NOT GOOD")
```

This will find if the promotion exists and the date is between the dates in the dataset.

If any are found then it returns "GOOD", otherwise it returns "NOT GOOD"

[image]